# Disabling all non-essential system resources

Tags: mac

I am running a lab experiment on my Macbook Pro and I'm calculating the results of a program (physics simulation) so I need all of the available CPU I can get. Since the program that I have to run requires full access to the GPU I cannot boot in safe mode because it seems to reduce the graphics quite a bit. Things that I am doing now:

Quitting all application (of course), quitting Finder, disabling all sharing services (in system preferences), plugging laptop into AC adapter, reducing screen brightness (not sure if it will help), turning off wifi/bluetooth, disabling time machine, disabling all notifications and disabling sounds.

This is probably sufficient but is there something else I could do?

Comment: Open the Activity monitor and see under My processes what else you can stop.

Comment: So far, that's the bestest answer that I've received. Turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable user defined non-essential system resources by:

1. Opening the Activity Monitor
2. Selecting the `My Processes` view:.
3. Sort by `Most Memory` and look at all memory-consuming processes.
4. Or Sort by CPU usage.

See the sample picture below:

[image]

Comment: Sorting by %CPU might be better to identify cpu-using processes